# Statements in for-loop not getting printed after using 'list(zip_variable)', but getting printed before using 'list(zip_variable)'

Tags: python, python-3.x

> The statement "Hello before using list(zip_shop)" is getting printed.
>
> The statement "Hello after using list(zip_shop)" is not getting printed.

```
groceries = ["apple","chips","bread","icecream"]
price = [2,3,1.2,4.25]
print("groceries = ",groceries,"and price =",price)

zip_shop = zip(groceries,price)

print("zip_shop =", zip_shop,"and type(zip_shop) =",type(zip_shop),"and id(zip_shop) = ",id(zip_shop))
for g, p in zip_shop:
    print("Hello before using list(zip_shop)")


print("list(zip_shop)=", list(zip_shop),"and type(zip_shop) =",type(zip_shop),"and id(zip_shop) = ",id(zip_shop))
for g, p in zip_shop:
    print("Hello after using list(zip_shop)")
```

Can someone please help me understand the behavior here?

Output is as below:

```
groceries =  ['apple', 'chips', 'bread', 'icecream'] and price = [2, 3, 1.2, 4.25]
zip_shop = <zip object at 0x0000022852A29948> and type(zip_shop) = <class 'zip'> and id(zip_shop) =  2372208335176
Hello before using list(zip_shop)
Hello before using list(zip_shop)
Hello before using list(zip_shop)
Hello before using list(zip_shop)
list(zip_shop)= [] and type(zip_shop) = <class 'zip'> and id(zip_shop) = 2372208335176

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, the `zip` function yields an iterator, which can only be consumed once, you have to convert it to a `list`:

```
zip_shop = list(zip(groceries, price))
```

Comment: If that is the case, shouldn't it print the statements of the 2nd loop if I comment the 1st loop? (I've tried this and it's not printing the statements of 2nd loop)

Comment: but you did a `list(zip_shop)` before the 2nd loop.

Comment: So what will I have to do, if I want to print the statements of both the loop in the scenario of the question?

Comment: @LokeshwarTailor as georgexsh already told you, in python3 `zip` yields an iterator, so the __first__ explicit (`for`) or implicit (`list(...)`) loop over it will consume the iterator. If you want to use it more than once, you have to __first__ build a list out of it, then iterate over that list.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the zip object in wrong way. Zip object iterators are Lazily evaluated which means that they are only evaluated when they are called and not evaluated more than once, this avoids repeated evaluation of the zip object. You have to call Zip() for iterative object when you want to iterate.

```
groceries = ["apple","chips","bread","icecream"]
price = [2,3,1.2,4.25]
print("groceries = ",groceries,"and price =",price)

#zip_shop = zip(groceries,price)

for g, p in zip(groceries,price):
    print("Hello before using list(zip_shop)")

print("List:",list(zip(groceries,price)))

for g, p in zip(groceries,price):
    print("Hello after using list(zip_shop)")
```